# Failed to send sms in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sms

New to android and I can't seem to be able to send any text to myself on my emulator. I have allowed permission in the manifest file and imported the necessary classes but still can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Detail extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button button5;
Spinner spinner2;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
EditText editText4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    editText4 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String contact = editText4.getText().toString();
            String message = "Help is on the way.";
            sendMessage(contact,message);
            Intent b = new Intent(Detail.this, End.class);
            startActivity(b);
        }
    });

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.selectissue,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage(String contact, String message)
{
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    try {
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(contact, null , message , null , null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS failed to send.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


 }
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Option"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_option" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Detail"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".End"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_end" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Feedback"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_feedback" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Student"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_student" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Incident"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_incident" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Help"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_help" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Wifi"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_wifi" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Basic"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_basic" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Guide"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_guide" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".VPN"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_vpn" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".VDI"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_vdi" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Location"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_location" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Phone"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_phone" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".config"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_config" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Script"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_script" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Signup"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_signup" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not send text messages via emulator if you want to test SMS feature then test it on real android device with activated sim card.